# Replace JavaScript included file with function

Tags: javascript, performance, include

Does anyone know how could I replace the included js-file **'modernizr.min.js'** with the function?

```
{{ **'modernizr.min.js'** | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

---

function:

```
;window.Modernizr=function(a,b,c){function z(a){j.cssText=a}function A(a,b){return z(m.join(a+";")+(b||""))}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, if you can show code before and after that will help

Answer (score 0):

```
if(true)
{
var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet1.css';
head.appendChild(link);

}else{
var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet2.css';
head.appendChild(link);
}
```